# Class keeps printing none

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a switchboard class that switches light switches on and off. I've figured out how to write the code but when I create my object and print it, it keeps printing None. I'm not sure what's wrong and why it prints None instead of the return statement "The following switches are on: " Even if none of the switches are on it should still print the string above. Can someone help me find out why it's printing out None instead of the string I want it to print?

```
def SwitchBoard(LightSwitch):
    '''This class will create a switch board for the user to use with n
    number of switches that is entered by the user'''

    def __init__(self, num_switches):
        '''
        (SwitchBoard, int) -> NoneType
        Given a value by the user, the function will create a switch board
        '''
        # create an empty list to be the switchboard with the desired amount
        # of switches
        self._listsw = [] 
        # turn each switch to off
        for index in range(num_switches):
            self._listsw.append(0)


    def __str__(self):
        '''
        (SwitchBoard) -> str
        Returns in a string the switches on the switchboard that are on
        '''
        # create an empty string to store the on switches in
        result = ""
        for index in range(len(self._listsw)):
            if(self._listsw[index] == 1):
                result += str(index)
                result += " "
        return "The following switches are on: " + result

def which_switch(self):
    '''
    (SwitchBoard) -> list of int
    Given a switchboard, the function will check to see which switches are
    on and will return the following switches in order as a list on integers
    '''
    # create an empty list to store the on switches in
    on_switches = []
    # loop through the list to check each switch
    for index in range(len(self._listsw)):
        # check if the switch is on
        if(self._listsw[index] == 1):
            # if the switch is on, add it to the list
            on_switches.append(index)
    # return the list of on switches
    return on_switches


def flip(self, n):
    '''
    (SwitchBoard, int) -> NoneType
    Given a switch as an integer, the function will flip the state of the
    desired switch on the switchboard. If it is on, it will be turned off.
    If it is off, it will be turned on.
    '''
    for index in range(len(self._listsw)):
        # check if the switch is on
        if(self._listsw[n] == 1):
            # if it is on, turn the switch off
            self._listsw[n] = 0
        # if the switch is off
        elif(self._listsw[n] == 0):
            # turn the switch on
            self._listsw[n] = 1            


def flip_every(self, n):
    '''
    (SwitchBoard, int) -> NoneType
    Given an integer n, the function will flip the state of every nth
    integer. If the integer is on, it will be turned off. If the integer is
    off, it will be turned on.
    '''
    for index in range(0, len(self._listsw), n):
        # check if the switch is on
        if(self._listsw[index] == 1):
            # if it is on, turn the switch off
            self._listsw[index] = 0
        # if the switch is off
        elif(self._listsw[index] == 0):
            # turn the switch on
            self._listsw[index] = 1            


def reset(self):
    '''
    (SwitchBoard) -> NoneTypen
    When called, the function will reset the entire switchboad and all
    switches will be turned off.
    '''
    # go through the switchboard
    for index in range(len(self._listsw)):
        # and turn every switch off
        self._listsw[index] = 0
```

Comment: Please paste your code in your question.

Comment: I posted a screenshot click "my code so far"

Comment: Yes, but we a copy paste is much better.

Comment: ok will do then

Comment: So my only issue is why does it keep printing None instead of what I want it to print? Is there something wrong with my __init__ method?

Comment: change `def` to `class` in your first line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple error: You are defining your class as a function.

Replace:

```
def SwitchBoard(LightSwitch):
```

with

```
class SwitchBoard(LightSwitch):
```

And you are good to go. As it currently stands, `SwitchBoard` is treated as a function with one argument which does not return anything...hence the `None`.

Comment: Damn, missed that.

Comment: Though, @shamanth-chedde , 
 prime example in favor of entire relevant code copy pasted as this wasn't visible on the originally attached image ;-)

Comment: oh jeez Idk how I missed that alright thank you so much!